# body of mail doesn't contain returns(\n) when using ruby's Net::IMAP library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mail-gem

I am using Ruby's Net::IMAP lib to fetch mail and am using Mail gems read_from_string function to get the body but what happens is the mail containing html part is displayed correctly but the one with only text/plain part are displayed continuously without any return character even if the original mail has them... please suggest something... thanks in advance !

MY CODE:

> Fetching the mail (I already have the uid)

```
    email = @imap.uid_fetch(uid, ["BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO DATE SUBJECT)]", "RFC822"])
```

> Extracting Headers and the body

```
header_attr = email[0].attr["BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO DATE SUBJECT)]"]
header      = Mail.read_from_string(header_attr)
message_attr = email[0].attr["RFC822"]
message      = Mail.read_from_string(message_attr)
```

> Checking for multipart

```
if message.multipart?
  @body = message.text_part.decoded.force_encoding("UTF8").encode("UTF-8")
else
  @body = message.body.decoded.force_encoding(message.charset).encode("UTF-8")
end
```

I use the @body.to_s in my view and it doesn't give correct output :(

> content type of a mail

Content-Type: text/plain; 
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: Just a quick guess - you say you are showing the `@body` in a view - are you certain that the line breaks are indeed not present in the decoded `@body`? HTML ignores all this whitespace, perhaps you just need to use `simple_format(@body)` in your view to retain line breaks?

Comment: Great! this thing worked for me straight away :) thanks a lot @BoraMa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @BoraMa in the above comment I just had to use simple_format(@body) in my view to display the body